# Exact Online API Returns XML Error

Tags: json, guzzle, exact-online

### What I do

I'm really confused about the following.

- I'm logged in via Exact Online oAuth2 (works)
- I'm redirected to the set redirect url (works)
- Now, I'm doing a POST request for creating an CRM Account to

https://start.exactonline.com/api/v1/1645882/crm/Accounts

with headers:

- Authorization: Bearer MY_TOKEN
- Content-Type: application/json

with json data:

```
{
    "Name": "James Fellows",
    "Code": "JF"
}
```

### Code (simplified)

```
$this->client->request('POST', 'https://start.exactonline.com/api/v1/1645882/crm/Accounts', ['headers' => ['Authorization' => 'Bearer MY_TOKEN']], ['json' => json_encode(['Name' => 'James Fellows', 'Code' => 'JF'])]);
```

### Problem

And now the problem. I always get this error:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<error xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">\r\n
    <code></code>
    <message xml:lang="">Error processing request stream. JSON text specified is not valid.
</message>
</error>
```

### Documentation

I used the following api documentation:

- https://developers.exactonline.com/#RestSampleCode.html%3FTocPath%3DExact%2520Online%2520REST%2520API%7CCode%2520examples%7C_____1
- https://start.exactonline.com/docs/HlpRestAPIResourcesDetails.aspx?name=CRMAccounts

Comment: I pass the headers content-type application/json. What do you mean?

Comment: A bit late, but you should consider using the Accept header to specify the preferred response format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just don't use `json_encode()` for your data if you use `json` option. This option accepts an array and automatically encodes it internally.

Answer (score -1):

You should omit the `ID` field. That field will be auto-filled.

There are also some problems with the formatting of your JSON (quotes to be specific). This one should do:

```
{ Code : 'JF'
, Name : 'Jeff Fellows'
}
```

Comment: Thank you. http://jsonlint.com returns "Valid JSON" with my json code. Should I use invalid json for Exact Online api?